# After installing @zeit/next-sass my next app wont start

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I've been playing around with NextJS for a couple of days, and after installing the @zeit/next-sass package, my app won't start. I am getting this error in the terminal: 
[image]

Everything was running fine before I installed the package. Could execute 'npm run dev' in the terminal and the server would start normally. 
Any help would be appreciated, I am fairly new to Next.

Comment: would you try to reinstall the deps: remove node_modules and install again `npm i -D`

Comment: next is not recognized! it means next is not installed may be on your project may be on your system globally!